# what for is /etc/default/sysstat?

Tags: services

I am trying to use sar in my system. So I had to install it and I did:
`sudo apt-get install sysstat`

After this if I do something like `sar -u 1` I got the info I want.

However according to sites like [this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/the-system-activity-reporter-sar-command-in-linux/) before I do this I have to edit `/etc/default/sysstat` and I have to restart the service with `service sysstat restart`

What for? the sar command is running already fine...

What for is the `/etc/default/sysstat` file exactly?